# "Mit einem" versus "mit einen"

Tags: usage, dative

When does one say *mit einem* and when does one say *mit einen*?

I am not sure of the difference, either in common usage or grammatically.

Answer (score 3):

You never say "mit einen", because **mit** is part of those prepositions that ONLY ONLY ONLY go with Dativ.

**Präposition mit Dativ** (These are some other preposition that, as well, work only with Dativ)

> mit, seit, von, aus, nach, bei, zu

Rememering them by heart will make your life much easier. Whenever you meet them, make the Dativ bell ring :)

Answer (score 2):

"mit einem" :

Always.

"mit" is a Dative preposition and "einen" is Accusative, so you can find "mit einen" precisely:

Never.

And no for the exception: of course it can technically occur after "mit" but then "mit" is not a preposition but a part of the verb.

> Kommst du mit einen Kaffee trinken.

"Einen Kaffee" is connected to "trinken" and has nothing to do with "mit", which is part of "mitkommen".

Comment: 1,240,000 results für [mit einen](https://www.google.de/search?client=opera&q=%22mit+einen%22&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest&gws_rd=ssl). Mit ganz wenigen Ausnahmen alles Fehler :(

Comment: @Em1... wow! "mit einen" sounds sooooo wrong to my ears.

Comment: I also searched, and found lots of min einen hits so I thought it had to had to be right somehow. But the exception to the rule could explain that handily.

Comment: Rare example using _mit_ as a preposition: _… hoch wachsender Baum mit einen Schopf bildenden gefiederten Blättern und kleinen, roten Blüten in Rispen._

Comment: @loong... nice :)